# Github actions failing because of 'Bad credentials'

Tags: github, github-actions, github-projects

I am running a github action aimed at our company's Github Project board but it is always failing with `This project is configured at the org level. Org Login:[our organization name], project number#1 #ERROR# HttpError: Bad credentials`

```js
Run konradpabjan/move-labeled-or-milestoned-issue@v2.0   with:
    project-url: https://github.com/orgs/[our project name]/projects/1
    column-name: Waiting
    label-name: blocked
    columns-to-ignore: Review,Ready 2 Merge,Done
```

I have a personal access token that has all rights, which seemed to be the solution in other projects.

It could be that I am missing some config that involves a token but I am not seeing anywhere online where i could fix this.